# DNS: Azure Server <-> SRV record (Godaddy)<-> Windows 2012 Domain Controller

Tags: azure, networking, dns, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm trying to add a Azure Server to an existing domain.  Windows2012 is looking for  *_ldap._tcp.dc._msdcs.learnsense.org*

How do I set up a Godaddy DNS SRV record that will point to my Domain Controller named *ATA-Server*?

For reference the fields are

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**I did it!**

For anyone else who wants to do this, I was able to use Godaddy DNS to host a SRV record enabling a domain join for my Azure server.

**How I did it!**

On the domain controller DNS there's a _msdcs.*domain* zone and a folder _tcp and record _ldap.  These DNS records are auto-populated when the server role DC is added.  (For me this server's DNS is only for the local (internal) network.

I used above record's values to configure the Godaddy DNS as in [their help page](https://support.godaddy.com/help/article/680/managing-dns-for-your-domain-names) .

I tested the record using nslookup in powershell like [shown in this page](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816587).  Added the Azure server to the domain and restarted.  ([If you need help with that.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms942519%28v=cs.70%29.aspx))

**That does it!**